# Returning to previous tab from another activity in android app

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I have this android app in which my main activity `HomeActivity` holds two `fragments` using a `ViewPager` and a `tab layout`. Each fragment holds a list of items and when clicked takes the user to another activity. Now I would like to return to the previous `tab layout` when the `back button` is pressed in the current activity. Simply put how do I get back to the tab layout from which the user had come from. Normally a back press would take the user to a default tab, in this case the `BtcFragment` tab but I would like to be able to return the user to the originally clicked tab in the HomeActivity.

Comment: Your chance of receiving a useful answer will be greatly increased if you only post the code that is relevant to your question.

Comment: Please, I would be grateful if you point out what isn't useful.

Comment: the majority of your code is not related to adding and removing fragments. By separating out the code that causes you trouble you give yourself and others a better chance of understanding what is wrong.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with my code per say I just wish to know how to go back to the previous tab when the user clicks the back button

Answer (score 0):

in your Main Activity or where you define your view pager create a static method as below :

```
public static void ViewPagerTabSelector(int tabNumber) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tabNumber);
}
```

then from activity you want to back in your `onbackpress call:

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   MainActivity.ViewPagerTabSelector(0);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the static method doesn't go well with the HomeActivity android is complaining!